# three js video position inside sphere

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am using three js to display video where the user can move through the video using mouse, example here:

https://threejs.org/examples/?q=video#webgl_video_panorama_equirectangular

the code: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/webgl_video_panorama_equirectangular.html

Is there a way to display where user is watching (position and direction) inside container, something like this:

http://ignitersworld.com/lab/imageViewer.html

In the top left corner there is a little square showing current position. I would like to know position and direction in which view is facing (all in 2D)

How could I achieve that?

---

edit:

orientation has been solved.

I am looking for position on the layout within video, is this possible? Like on the picture: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AEmPp.jpg

Comment: Nothing is impossible. You may be able to use a trick by using the frame number and linking that to spatial positions. But unless you have a SLAM representation of the video and some reference 3d design of the space on the side, it's extremely hard to get accurate coordinates out of it in node.js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the camera direction and calculate the angles. These angles will be your 2D orientation on a sphere:

```
var dir = camera.getWorldDirection();
var groundProjection = dir.clone().projectOnPlane(new THREE.Vector3(0,1,0))
var longitudeRadians = Math.atan2(groundProjection.x, groundProjection.z);
var latitudeRadians = Math.atan2(groundProjection.length(), dir.y)

// longitudeRadians is now an angle between -3.14 and 3.14
// latitudeRadians is now an angle between 0 and 3.14
```

Here is a running example: https://jsfiddle.net/holgerl/bqvdotps/

Comment: Thanks! I again did not think about performance. I have used your suggestions and fixed the excessive vector creation during projection with `groundProjection = camera.getWorldDirection(groundProjection).projectOnPlane(scene.up)` @WestLangley

Comment: @WestLangley Aside from orientation where camera is watching, would it be possible to get position within the video as in this picture? https://imgur.com/a/xsNYM In other words, position where user is within the video related to layout?